# Intellij idea auto import across files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have auto import enabled in idea, but it requires me to open the file in the editor (like it should). Now, i have done some regex magic, which means across 100+ classes i am using new classes that need to be imported. Since its all done with find/replace, those files have never been opened in the editor, and therefore the new classes havent been auto imported. Is there any way to run auto import unambiguous references across all files? cause currently, i have to compile, and then open all the files from the errors window? Optimize imports aparently doesnt do new imports.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this since it actually IS an useful question. I'm with the same problem right now. Have you found any solution?

Comment: nope, ended up find/replacing to add the import to all files below an import i knew they all had. Then optimised imports to remove it where it wasnt used

Comment: Yeah, I had to do quite the same: basically made a script to automatically insert the desired import in all workspace files, then after IDEA indexing them, I optimized their imports so the ones that didn't required the import wouldn't carry it unnecessarily.

Comment: Could you show us the script please?

Comment: Please use the short cut ctrl+alt+o

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Ctrl+Alt+o doesn't help

Comment: I've used the following script to add import to every java file in the project directory
`find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '2i import com.example.package.ExampleClass;' {} \;`
This command inserts desired import at the second line of the every java file. Next Ctrl+Alt+O puts the line on its place and removes it if it was not neccessary

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure in which version of IntelliJ this feature became available (I am currently using 2017.1.1) but you can select a package from the project browser and in the context menu optimise imports for that package or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

I just used this to update the imports of all my classes after changing my import settings and it worked like charm.

Comment: As far as I know this option only reformat the existing imports. What if you want to add an import for a unimported symbol that is used in the file?

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv I would recommend checking out the [auto-import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#disable-wildcard-imports) settings.